# How to get FeatureManager in ConfigureServices?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

ASP.NET Core 3 Web Server.
appsettings.json
"FeatureManagement": {
      "RouteStrategy": false
    },

I'd like to get configuration and add route in the function.
How to get the FeatureManager  here to analyze what features IsEnabled?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddFeatureManagement();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

            // <---------???
            //
```

Comment: Do you mean to get the value of RouteStrategy from `appsettings.json` in `ConfigureServices` method? If so , you could use `var flag = Configuration.GetSection("FeatureManagement:RouteStrategy").Value;`You could refer to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core) for the more details about using  feature flags in an ASP.NET Core app

Comment: Yes, its ok. Thnx, But how to do the same using FeatureManagement? https://andrewlock.net/introducing-the-microsoft-featuremanagement-library-adding-feature-flags-to-an-asp-net-core-app-part-1/

Comment: Are you able to add the specific case you're trying to support? Do you want the feature manager when you're configuring the DI container (that's what it looks like)? It's possible to get hold of a feature manager instance at various points but I would suggest almost all are once the service provider has been created.